How can I increase the stack size limit in a Go program?
I'm running a recursive implementation of the Quick Sort algorithm for my Algorithms Design class. My project requires me to run the algorithm with arrays from size 100 to size 10^8.
The algorithm can finish execution with a randomly distributed array (best case) of size 10^7. The problem starts when attempting execution on the ordered array of size 10^7.
Here's the implementation of the algorithm:
func partition(arr []int32, low, high int) ([]int32, int) {
    pivot := arr[high]
    i := low
    for j := low; j < high; j++ {
        if arr[j] < pivot { // Key instruction One: comparison for partitioning
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i] // Key instruction Two: swap
            i++
            keyInstructionTwoCount++
        }
        keyInstructionOneCount++
    }
    arr[i], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i] // Key instruction Two: swap
    keyInstructionTwoCount++

    return arr, i
}

func quickSort(arr []int32, low, high int) []int32 {
    if low < high {
        var p int
        arr, p = partition(arr, low, high)
        arr = quickSort(arr, low, p-1)
        arr = quickSort(arr, p+1, high)
    }
    return arr
}

I get the following error when the runtime detects the routine is exceeding the stack limit:
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit

Duplicate: How to increase stack limit from 1GB

If your recursive quicksort exceed such a large stack your implementation is broken. Expected recursion (=stack) depth for 1e8 elements is around 30. Stop increasing the stack depth and fix the algorithm.

You should probably read What is the XY problem?

Your program exhibits quadratic runtime when there's either a lot of duplicate elements, or the input is almost sorted. The common solution to these problems are to use a 3-way pivot (<pivot =pivot >pivot), and to choose a random pivot rather than one at the end of the array.
In addition, you can reduce the depth of recursion by only recursing on the shorter sub-array. That looks like this:
func quickSort(arr []int32, low, high int) []int32 {
    for low < high {
        var p int
        arr, p = partition(arr, low, high)
        if p - low > high - p {
            arr = quickSort(arr, p+1, high)
            high = p-1
        } else {
            arr = quickSort(arr, low, p-1)
            low = p+1
        }
    }
    return arr
}

This guarantees that the depth of recursion is O(log n), even if the runtime becomes quadratic.
(Also, I'm not sure why you're returning the input slice, since the algorithm is in-place and never returns anything but the slice you give it).
